# run jobs in straight without interleaving on gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using GitLab 8.8.2-ee.
I want to avoid 'interleaving' of jobs.

suppose a repo R has jobs A and B where B depends on A.
If there are multiple commits, jobs are interleaved sometimes like

A1 -> A2 -> B1 -> B2

But I want the following order:

A1 -> B1 -> A2 -> B2 or A2 -> B2 -> A1 -> A1

Is there any way to force this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group your jobs into *one* job, which would define stages in [its `.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/)

See "[Run jobs sequentially](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/07/29/the-basics-of-gitlab-ci/#run-jobs-sequentially)"

> We only want to run the 'package' job if the tests are successful. Let's define the order by specifying stages:

```
stages:
  - test
  - package

test:
  stage: test
  script: cat file1.txt file2.txt | grep -q 'Hello world'

package:
  stage: package
  script: cat file1.txt file2.txt | gzip > packaged.gz
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - packaged.gz
```

Comment: If you push commits repeatedly this will still lead to stage "test" being executed for each commit before continuing to state "package". This means you'll have a whole lot of unfinished jobs waiting for all "test" stages to finish before continuing. Is there a way to always finish all stages from a job first before continuing to the next job?

Comment: @wkarl Not sure actually: that could be a good question on its own.